# Is there a utility to cue up several strings for clipboard pasting (for step-by-step code presentations)?

Tags: clipboard, utility

I was at Apple WWDC in 2008 and all the engineers used some sort of utility to cue up 10-20 lines of code for easy pasting, one at a time. They used this to demonstrate code construction on the fly. It let them avoid having to actually type any Cocoa code in front of the large audiences.

I'm looking for a similar utility for doing screencasts. Anyone know of a good program that lets you cue up / manage multiple strings of text for easy pasting?

UPDATE: The program needs to be for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

For those window users out there who see this question, use [ClipX](http://www.bluemars.org/clipx/)

For Max OS... hopefully someone else is more useful than I can be.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, I don't use Mac OS, but a quick [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=os+x+clipboard+manager) revealed this: 
http://theappleblog.com/2009/06/02/10-clipboard-managers-for-os-x/